# Google oauth button issue with COOP

Tags: google-oauth, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

The issue is: since i locked my page up in order to use sharedArrayBuffer (and other perks) google auth throws an error at posting a message between windows:
   `m=credential_page_library:210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage') at Cj (m=credential_page_library:210:183) at Dj (m=credential_page_library:210:105)`   
//...
google popup get rendered empty.

setup:
headers:
 `res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp'); res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'cross-origin');`

script: `<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

it's a callback method.

is there a way to make it work? anyone?

it doesn't throw an error on script load. it shows an empty button with "Google" gray thing.

well i have an idea to run a separate server for authentication purposes and do a token-verified sing-up-in between the two origins. but that's far from ideal.

is there a way to allow google to do it's thing some how explicitly?